# Nuxt, splitting up Vuex store into separate files gives error: unknown mutation type: login

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm trying to **split up my Nuxt Vuex store files into separate files**. And NOT have all **Vuex** `getters`, `mutations` and `actions` into one huge file. This [demo project is on Github](https://github.com/dutchwebworks/nuxt-learning/tree/feature/vuex-separation) by the way.

I'v read [this official Nuxt Vuex Store documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode); but can't seem to get it working. It's a bit vague on where to put stuff.

I have the following in these files:

#### Below is my: store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Auth from "./modules/auth";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {

        },
        modules: {
            Auth
        }
    })
}
```

#### This is in my: store/auth.js

```
const state = () => {
    username: null
};

const getters = {
    username: state => {
        return state.username;
    },
    isAuthenticated: state => {
        return state.username != null;
    }
};

const mutations = {
    login: (vuexContext, username) => {
        vuexContext.username = username;
        this.$router.push("/dashboard");
    },
    logout: vuexContext => {
        vuexContext.username = null;
        this.$router.push("/");
    }
};

const actions = {

};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

#### And finally in my: pages/index.vue

This is where I'm calling that **login** mutation:

```
<script>
    export default {
        layout: "non-logged-in",
        data() {
            return {
                username: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                this.$store.commit("login", this.username);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### The error I'm getting:

`[vuex] unknown mutation type: login`

What am I doing wrong here? I thought i'm importing all the stuff correctly in the `store/index.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to export your store constant like this inside your store/index.js file:

```
export default store
```

Put this code line at the end of your file.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Together with some other changes; I got it working now.

Answer (score 4):

So as @jeremy.raza described this is what I changed in order to get it working:

#### store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Auth from "./modules/auth";

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {

        },
        modules: {
            Auth
        }
    })
}

export default store;
```

#### Changes in the store/auth.js

Note the changes in how I wrote the `state`, `getters` and `mutations` method notation.

```
const state = () => ({
    username: null
});

const getters = {
    username(state) {
        return state.username;
    },
    isAuthenticated(state) {
        return state.username != null;
    }
};

const mutations = {
    login(vuexContext, username) {
        vuexContext.username = username;
        this.$router.push("/dashboard");
    },
    logout(vuexContext) {
        vuexContext.username = null;
        this.$router.push("/");
    }
};

const actions = {

};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dennis Burger. I managed to use Vuex in module mode.

Comment: its getting deprecated, what will be the new way to implement this?
As of Nuxt 3, it will be removed.