# Unable to find Vuex module action in Nuxt

Tags: authentication, vuejs2, axios, csrf, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt site with a custom Django back end, and I'm trying to set up a mechanism where when the app loads, I call a `/token/` URL to get a CSRF token, and then store it in Vuex state to be used in a custom header that is set for every subsequent request.

First, here is my `store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from '@/store/auth'

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
      auth
    }
  })
}
export default store
```

and `store/auth.js`:

```
import { SET_TOKEN } from './types'

const state = () => ({
  token: ''
})

const getters = {
  token: state => state.token
}

const actions = {
  setToken({ commit, dispatch }, token) {
    commit(SET_TOKEN)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  [SET_TOKEN](state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

One thing I can't figure it is where to put my mounted function so it's always triggered on page reload. In a regular Vue app, it's App.vue, but I haven't been able to find what that same thing is in Nuxt. For now, I just use `index.vue`. I'm also using the @axios Nuxt module to communicate with the back end.

```
<script>
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.getCSRFToken()
  },
  methods: {
    async getCSRFToken() {
      // Call the URL that sets the csrftoken cookie
      const tokenRequest = await this.$axios.$get('/token/')
      // Get the cookie value
      const token = Cookie.get('csrftoken')
      // Save it to the store./
      this.$store.dispatch('auth/setToken', token)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I can call the URL just fine and get the value from the cookie, but when I go to dispatch my action, I get an error that says `[vuex] unknown action type: auth/setToken`.

I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008997/nuxt-splitting-up-vuex-store-into-separate-files-gives-error-unknown-mutation) to set up my state. My questions are these:

1. What is a common starting point in Nuxt that I can use to always load this on page refresh/initial load?
2. What do I need to change in my setup so that my action is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `auth` module is not namespaced.

Change the default export to

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

You should probably remove `namespaced: true` from your root store.

---

I recommend you change to using Nuxt's [Module Mode](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#modules-mode) as the [Classic Mode](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#classic-mode) you're using will be removed in Nuxt 3. For example

```js
// store/auth.js
import { SET_TOKEN } from './types'

export const state = () => ({
  token: ''
})

export const actions = {
  setToken({ commit, dispatch }, token) {
    commit(SET_TOKEN)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  [SET_TOKEN](state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
}
```

Comment: So then if I"m using Module Mode, I don't have to set `namespaced: true` anywhere, correct?